# C# Jump to bookmarks in PDF help file

Tags: c#, pdf

My relatively large program has a PDF help file which I have put together. It has quite a few bookmarks so I could theoretically jump to any of those points in the document when a user requests help.

Is there any way I can open the PDF and jump straight to a bookmark from C#?

I have put the document together in Word 2007 with bookmarks, cross-references, headings and ToC, and saved it as a PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf) out. You can pass `nameddest=name` for bookmarks or `page=pagenum` for pages to Acrobat when you start the process from your program and it should open to that place in the PDF.